# docker-machine create node without tls verification

Tags: docker, docker-machine

When I create a node with **docker-machine**

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox node1
```

it is created with tls verification enabled for docker deamon which made things a bit more of a hassle than normal for swarm.

I want to create a node with **docker-machine** without tls verification for testing purpose.

I tried with:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-tls false node1
```

and

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-tls-verify false node1
```

and

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-opt-tls false node1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-opt tlsverify=false node1
```

and after running:

```
eval "$(docker-machine env node1)"
```

run:

```
unset DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. When  I follow the above steps and try run a container on the machine I get:

```docker run hello-world
Post http://192.168.99.104:2376/v1.21/containers/create: malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02\x16".
* Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?```

Comment: the docker engine process in the vm still has the tls flags set: `/usr/local/bin/docker daemon -D -g /var/lib/docker -H unix:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 --label provider=virtualbox --tlsverify=false --tlsverify --tlscacert=/var/lib/boot2docker/ca.pem --tlscert=/var/lib/boot2docker/server.pem --tlskey=/var/lib/boot2docker/server-key.pem -s aufs`

Comment: after creating the notls vm,  `docker-machine ls` give error msg about it :`Unable to query docker version: Get https://192.168.99.101:2376/v1.15/version: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client`

Answer (score 7):

I use commands below:

```
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-env DOCKER_TLS=no node1
```

And then ssh to the node to execute docker commands:

```
docker-machine ssh node1
$ docker info
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked best for me:

`docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-env DOCKER_TLS=no --engine-opt host=tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 node1`

This way it binds to 2375 in addition to 2376. 2375 is the tradition for non-tls daemons.

Comment: This works, but docker-machine throws an error at the end and `docker-machine env` also throws an error so you have to set the env manually to get the docker client working.

Comment: docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-env DOCKER_TLS=no  node1
Also works! And it doesn't expose additional port since it is not needed