# How to create a docker machine without TLS to use in Mac Env with Java

Tags: java, macos, docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

My needs is to use Docker-Machine to create development env with Docker engine installed. The problem comes from with Mac because from Mac if I run Java program, I could not be connected to the socket.

We can read here : [Official Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/https/) that

> Warning: These TLS commands will only generate a working set of
>   certificates on Linux. Mac OS X comes with a version of OpenSSL that
>   is incompatible with the certificates that Docker requires.

I wonder how to do it. I search here into other issue but no way to be right. For example : [docker-machine create node without tls verification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30717347/docker-machine-create-node-without-tls-verification)

Second question : how do you do it to connect the docker client in MacOsX to TLS Socket ? Do you import and compile a specific implementation and not use openssl from Mac ?

Thanks you very much.
Best regards,
Nicolas

---

For example, this command line is not right : Wrong ?

docker-machine create -d virtualbox --engine-env DOCKER_TLS=no --engine-opt host=tcp://0.0.0.0:2375 node